# pandas DataFrame is not handling decimal point numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe with which I am performing maths on each value, deviding small numbers by large numbers. This should leave with me with very small decimal point numbers, but my dataframe is just converting these to 0.

An example would be that I divide 2577 by 3022356 which gives me 0.0008526460814013968, but the entry in the dataframe is just 0.

Is there anything I can do so that the dataframe displays the correct value?

Example in my code:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    for key in row.keys():
        row[key] = float(row[key]) / float(row['total'])

    data.iloc[index] = row
```

This iterates through every row, iterates through all the keys in each row except that last two. Then decides each value with a total. I have added the `float()` based on suggestion but the value placed back into data is just 0 as opposed to the correct value.

Comment: Which python version are you using? in Python 3.X a/b should return a float. Otherwise you can import `division` from `__future__`.  Please add more information about your problem like your dataframe's columns dtype, a small snippet of code , etc.

Comment: Using 3.7, so am not sure why this is happening. I have also edited the question to include an exaple

Comment: That's lot of loops in your code. Show  a sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: @SreeramTP can you elaborate? Two loops? Can you present a way to loop through each row and each item in each row with less?

Comment: You have not mentioned what is your desired output. Why are you slicing from index 611.? To apply something over rows you can use apply in pandas. Read the docs for further info

Answer (score -1):

You can set the numerator and denumerator to floating point to make sure the conversion is right, so it would be float(2577)/float(3022356).

Comment: Yeah I have tried to do this, but when the result is placed back into the dataframe it just ends up as 0

Comment: @BenRichi_ Try it with numpy.longfloat, this problem happens because your number is too small for a normal float.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little example of what the code will look like, but within your DataFrame you might want to use the function df.loc[(row_index),(column_index)] to call the numbers from within the DataFrame.

```
number1 = float(2577)
number2 = float(3022356)

answer = number1/number2

print(answer)
```

you could also try this

```
x = df.loc[row,column]
flo = float(x)
x = "{0:.10f}".format(flo)
#print(x)
df.loc[row,column] = x
```

this would tell it to format it as 10 decimal places

Comment: Hi @akerr, I have edited my question to show an example of where this is happening

Comment: @BenRichi_ what type of value does row return when you type(row)?